# Subscribing to a git repository on slack

Tags: github, slack

Can someone tell me like I'm 5 on subscribing to a git repository on slack? My google-fu is not giving any answers.

I have five repositories, none of which I'm the owner on. I want a slack notification when there's a push to these repositories. If I type /github help I get a list of commands and it says I should be able to subscribe by "/github subscribe owner/repository"

I'm not sure which people on my team "own" the repository and I'm not sure where this information is in github.

I read somewhere I could just do /github subscribe and paste the full https link, but I get this back

[image]

If I click Install button I get a page that says "Where do you want to install slack?"

If I select configure under my github main repo, I get this:

[image]

If I start adding repositories, everyone on my team gets an email notification to add slack to github. I don't get an email notification. Nothing happens at all. Then everyone in the company pings me asking me why they're getting slack/github notifications. To prevent further humiliation, I just stopped trying to add the repo. I'd still like to add it though.

Comment: Are you an Owner on your Slack team?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not an administrator on slack if that's what you mean.

Comment: I know that some Slack teams restrict Slack App configuration permissions to administrators/owners only. You should see if a Slack Admin on your team is able to add the GitHub app to Slack for you.

Answer (score 2):

> I should be able to subscribe by "/github subscribe owner/repository"

> I'm not sure which people on my team "own" the repository and I'm not sure where this information is in github.

I just wanted to help with this part, since I recently had to figure that same thing out.  The owner is the organization that your repositories belong to.  So, lets say you have a repo named "RepoOne".  If you click into that repo, the URL in the address bar should show:  "https://github.com/[owner]/RepoOne"

So, you should be able to copy the owner and repo name from your URL and use it in the command as follows:

`/github subscribe [owner]/RepoOne`

Keep in mind, that only subscribes you to the `isssues`, `pulls`, `commits`, `releases`, and `deployments`.  I like to include the `reviews` and `comments` too, so I go with:

`/github subscribe [owner]/RepoOne reviews comments`